# Current logged in user on IIS in Vue.js application

Tags: vue.js, authentication, iis

I currently have a single page Vue.js application being hosted on an IIS server. The application speaks to a .Net Core web service hosted on the same server. I’ve got Windows Authentication turned on for the client site, and I need to know the best way to get the current logged in user of the vue.js application.

Comment: Your .NET Core web service can easily learn the user name, so let vue.js app asks it for that.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you could not get the windows user in vue js. if you want to get the windows user identity in .net core site you could use below code:

In ConfigureServices

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

In controller

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {           
            _httpContextAccessor =  httpContextAccessor;
            string userName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;     
        }
```